# How do I manually install Skyrim mods while using PlayOnLinux?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc, linux

I'm using PlayOnLinux and can't find the working mods folder for Skyrim. Help!

Comment: Is that the Steam version ?

Comment: Yes. It indeed is.

Answer (score 1):

PlayOnLinux is just a user-friendly GUI for Wine, a free implementation of Windows on Unix. When you install a game, it creates a virtual drive, which default location is `$HOME/PlayOnLinux' s virtual drives/<name of the game>`.

In that virtual drive, **the folder "drive_c" is just like "C:\" on Windows**.

Hence, for the steam version, the folder you are looking for is `drive_c/Program Files/steam/steamapps/common/The Elder Scrolls V Skyrim/Data`.

Comment: Cheers mate! Time to see if getting mods from Nexus works...